# Qpython, socket connection error

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, qpython3

I'm learning server- and client-side connections:
What I'm attempting to do is connecting  server- and client-side scripts with each other on *Qpython*(android)

The problem is when I run it, it gives me this:

> "ConnectionRefusedError: Errno [111] Connection Refused"

When I run the same scripts on my computer it gives me no error.

Background information:

- I'm using 2 different apps on my phone
- And 1 on my computer.

  But I suppose that can't be the problem

> Client

```
import socket 
import sys 

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999 

Data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:]) + input(" Enter Message:\n"

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket) 

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

try: 
 # Connect to server and send data
 sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
 sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8")) 
# Receive data from the server and shut down 
 received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")
finally: 
 sock.close() 

print("Sent: {}".format(data)) 
print("Received: {}".format(received))
```

> Server

```
import socketserver 

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler): 

 def handle(self): 

  # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client 

  self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip() 
  print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])) 
  print(self.data) 
# just send back the same data, but upper-cased 

self.request.sendall(self.data.upper()) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
 HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999 

# Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999 

 server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) 
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: post some code please, server is rejecting client.

Comment: OK Zombro, I've done so

Comment: No it's not the server, it's the host.

Comment: On a computer it works fine, but I mean my phone is giving the error

Comment: I know that I asked this question a year and a half ago, but I found what causes the problem: My phone (as host) is not allowing 3rd party apps to communicate with the internet or other apps.